# how to find first alphabetic character from a string

Tags: android, regex, string

Lets say I have a string `"12345.6789abcd23"`
so my string starts with a numbers then alphabetic characters then it may contains other numbers 
so what I want is `"12345.6789"` and `"abcd23"`
please note that this is just an example so `indexOf()` will not help,
if I can get the index of first alphabetic that would be great

Comment: use regular expressions to find it

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework assignment. I'm sure if you showed what you wrote and how you attempted it people would be willing to point out where it went pear shaped.

Comment: try to search your own solution at http://www.regxlib.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` to achieve that:

```
final Pattern line = Pattern.compile("^[^a-zA-Z]+(.).*");
final Matcher m = line.matcher(your_line);
if (m.matches())
  Log.d("FirstLetter", "My first letter is: " + m.group(1));
```

This basically will use a regexp and get rid of anything that don't match the range between `a-z` and `A-Z` from the beggining of your `String` and then return the first character just after it, which is expected to be a alphabetic character. So that's why it's between parentheses, to get it with `.group(1)`.

- The first `^` from the `compile` sentence represents the beggining of the `String` to be matched.
- Anything between `[]` represents a set. So there I'm representing a range, `a-z` will expand to any alphabetic character. The `^` in the beggining of the set means a different thing, though. It means **not**, so I want to get rid of anything that doesn't match a alphabetic character.
- The plus sign (`+`) represents that this set is meant to have at least 1 and at most infinite number of characters which match the above set. If there's a situation where you could not get a non-alphabetic character at the beggining of the `String`, use `*` instead of the `+`. This represents *any* number of occurences, including **zero**.
- The very next letter *will* be alphabetic, so I want to grab it, I represent it with a dot (`.`). A dot represents *any* char for *once*. I wrap it with parentheses because I want to be able to pick it somehow with a `Matcher`.
- I don't mind the rest, just put .* (any char any times (including 0-times)

Comment: and thank you for the explanation :D , I am still new with Java